# Need help understanding "garbage" data in https request

Tags: android, java, apk, byte-code, https-protocol

I managed to overcome certificate pinning in an android application and I am now able to view all the HTTPS request in plain text. However, I came across this request that I still do not understand:

[image]

We can see that it is a POST request with some 'junk' data at the bottom. At first, I thought this 'junk' is some form of encrypted data. However, after looking at the decompiled source code, it does not seem to use any form of encryption as shown below.

```
@Override
public List<byte[]> sendBatch(String serializable, List<byte[]> list) throws AmazonClientException {
    void var2_7;
    void var1_3;
    if (var2_7 == null || var2_7.isEmpty()) {
        List list2 = Collections.emptyList();
        return var1_3;
    } else {
        PutRecordBatchRequest putRecordBatchRequest = new PutRecordBatchRequest();
        putRecordBatchRequest.setDeliveryStreamName((String)((Object)serializable));
        ArrayList<Record> arrayList = new ArrayList<Record>(var2_7.size());
        for (byte[] arrby : var2_7) {
            Record record = new Record();
            record.setData(ByteBuffer.wrap(arrby));
            arrayList.add(record);
        }
        putRecordBatchRequest.setRecords(arrayList);
        putRecordBatchRequest.getRequestClientOptions().appendUserAgent(this.userAgent);
        PutRecordBatchResult putRecordBatchResult = this.client.putRecordBatch(putRecordBatchRequest);
        int n2 = putRecordBatchResult.getRequestResponses().size();
        ArrayList arrayList2 = new ArrayList(putRecordBatchResult.getFailedPutCount());
        int n3 = 0;
        do {
            ArrayList arrayList3 = arrayList2;
            if (n3 >= n2) return var1_3;
            if (putRecordBatchResult.getRequestResponses().get(n3).getErrorCode() != null) {
                arrayList2.add(var2_7.get(n3));
            }
            ++n3;
        } while (true);
    }
}
```

I searched for the method putRecordBatch and came across the docs: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/firehose/latest/APIReference/API_PutRecordBatch.html
and realise that the syntax is of the form:

```
{
   "DeliveryStreamName": "string",
   "Records": [ 
      { 
         "Data": blob
      }
   ]
}
```

where I believe the 'junk' data is simply just another form of the json object above. Is there any way I can convert this junk data to a more readable form?

Comment: The problem is that your https request is full of squiggly red lines :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The content is encoded with gzip per the `Content-encoding` header. You can use the decoder in Burp proxy (if that is what you are currently using) to decode the data or by using for intance `gunzip` in the Linux command line.

Comment: Hi I tried Decoding as gzip using Burp decoder but the output still doesn't make sense. Maybe I'm supposed to copy the output to a file? Is there any way I can copy the hex values from burp decoder? When I try to copy the values raw and paste it in any editor, the whole output gets shrunk to just 2 bytes

Comment: ah nevermind i got it to decode properly using smart decode instead of gzip decode